# How to design an inline structure that will render superscript immediately above subscript?

Tags: html, css

I would like to reproduce the mathematical notation A<sub>sub</sub><sup>sup</sup>, but with "sup" right above "sub".

The following code is close, but not quite there.

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sup {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="sup">
      sup
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
      sub
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What would be a more correct way for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flexbox.

Flex in an inline element could look like this:

```
<p class="expression">
  Before <span class="script"><span>Sup</span><span>Sub</span></span> After
</p>
```

CSS

```
.expression {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.script {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.script span {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qom7L03y/3/

Comment: nice, but text that is placed before and after the outer div is not rendered on the same line as the div

Comment: yes. the only problem now is that the text must be inside the flex div for this to work. I'm looking for an independent inline structure

Comment: Ah, if you could apply the same properties to a p tag, if you wanted to go with flex.  I'll look into inline-block, but I have a strong feeling you won't be able to solve your problem using vertical align.

Comment: Changed my suggestion to fit as an independent structure.